# E: Version '2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1' for 'libglib2.0-0' was not found

Tags: package-management, glib

I am doing mlperf.

///// update 2 /////

main page:

https://mlperf.org/

github and testing steps:

https://github.com/mlperf/training/tree/master/object_detection

Just follow the README.md, until this step:

```
cd training/object_detection/
nvidia-docker build . -t mlperf/object_detection
```

This problem will show up as:

```
E: Version '2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1' for 'libglib2.0-0' was not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -y  && apt-get install -y apt-utils=1.2.29ubuntu0.1                        libglib2.0-0=2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1                        libsm6=2:1.2.2-1                        libxext6=2:1.3.3-1                        libxrender-dev=1:0.9.9-0ubuntu1' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I need 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1, but it seems system installed 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.2.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0=2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1
```

but got:

```
E: Version '2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1' for 'libglib2.0-0' was not found
```

OS: ubuntu 16.04.6 desktop.

/////// update /////////

```
~/tmp$ apt-cache madison libglib2.0-0
libglib2.0-0 | 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.2 | http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
libglib2.0-0 | 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.2 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
libglib2.0-0 | 2.48.0-1ubuntu4 | http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: The command `apt-cache madison libglib2.0-0` will show you all the versions available for installation from the repositories currently setup on your system.

Comment: Thanks, it did show no expected package, and I can't remove the original package in the system by 'apt-get purge libglib2.0-0'

Comment: It lists many ( > 20 ) depends, last line is 'E: Unmet depedencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages.'

Comment: After try this line 'apt-get install' then remove, it can remove now.

Comment: Sorry, it can remove the package in the system, but I still no idea how to install the target version 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1

Comment: I can find the file here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1 but I would have to do some testing and setup of 16.04 to test it out for you.  I would have to do that later.

Comment: I think the link still has no target version: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/libglib2.0-0

Comment: *"I need 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1"* No, you don't.

Comment: @Terrance When a neW version is released, the old one is removed. That's how all repos work.

Comment: @Mark If you could [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1150922/edit) your question showing what exactly you are doing and that you need this specific version.  I have been trying to find the `mlperf` and I am not coming up with anything.

Comment: @Mark Thank you for the edit.  Unfortunately I might not be much more help beyond here, but I guess you could always try changing the  `training/object_detection/Dockerfile` on your system after you clone it to reflect the `libglib2.0-0=2.48.2-0ubuntu4.2` file instead and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I fix the problem:

Edit the training/object_detection/Dockerfile and replace the line:

> libglib2.0-0=2.48.2-0ubuntu4.1 \

with:

> libglib2.0-0 \

will fix the issue by removing the hardcoded glib version.